# FastCGI on Windows and Lighttpd

Tags: c, windows, cgi, fastcgi, lighttpd

I'm looking to make my CGI forum software FastCGI compatible.
The forum software consists of a few dlls and .exe (.cgi) files written in C and x86 assembly language. I also have a SQlite3 database.

Lighttpd runs all these cgi scripts as child processes and I much say that the whole thing works pretty damn well.

But I want to experiment with FastCGI. However, the examples are poor, the documentation is poor, and it really looks like it's made for Linux in mind. Did someone get FastCGI working on Windows? If someone has a code example around, and the lighttpd configuration lines, I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i've done some work with fastcgi on windows. bottom line is its not a lot of fun - you are 100% correct that there aren't a lot of sample and it the documentation is poor. but, the developer who i was helping on this was in contact with the guys who write iis and the fastcgi spec and was able to get his software to work. some changes are in the works to help. here is a link to some information:

http://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/archive/2009/04/20/fastcgi-isapi-1-5-beta-for-winxp-and-win2k3.aspx

i should add that the guy i was working with had so many problems with libfcgi.dll that he ended up rewriting it (see the reference to libfcgi2.dll in the article linked above.)

best regards,
don

Comment: Great! Now I have a DLL... 
Alright, let's do this.
I give you my thanks Don!

Comment: See www.coastrd.com for more.